# Add categories to a page with out using Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

My current site has custom post types, that run of off the root domain, so anything created inside the CPT will be something like: domain.com/page-name/ rather than domain.com/custom-post-type-name/post-name/. With this, I want to update to WP 4.7 but I cannot because it breaks my website and the CPT's mess up.

Here's why I'm using custom post types, so I have this page template that pulls in everything related to that custom post type and displays those pages a list (similar to the blog page).

However, seeing as everything is of off the root. I was wondering if there was a way to customise Wordpress to give me the option to add a category to a PAGE, therefore, after I can create a code that will display all PAGES within that CATEGORY as a page template.

Reason for this, is will allow me to update to Wordpress 4.7 and not have 5-10 different CPT's as it just gets annoying clicking between the different custom post type labels in the backend.

If anyone has any ideas or know's off a plugin that will do this.

And maybe if some has the code to show all pages as a list, that sit under that category, that would be great - please share.

Thanks.

**Update**

Here's my code for loop:

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                            <?php $query = new WP_Query( array( post_type=page, 'cat' => 541 ) ); ?>
```

have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

```
                                            <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                                the_post_thumbnail(array(150,150));
                                            } else {
                                                echo '<img class="alignleft" src="'.get_bloginfo("template_url").'/images/empty_150_150_thumb.gif" width="150" height="150" />';
                                            }
                                            ?>


                                            <div class="entry">
                                                <h3 class="blog_header"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link: <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                                <a class="button_link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span>Read More</span></a>

                                            </div>  


                                    </div>
```

I'm attempting to display the pages that have been added to that category within a loop. Is there something wrong with my loop?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean to say you need something like categories to be assigned into posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to attach the default post category taxonomy, you can always create a new one specifically for pages.  Insert this into your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_page_taxonomies' );
function create_page_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy('page_category', 'page', array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x( 'Page Category', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'page-category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Page Categories' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Page Categories' ),
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Page Category' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Page Category:' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Page Category' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Page Category' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Page Category' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Page Category Name' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Page Categories' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'page-category',
            'with_front' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true
        )
    ));
}
```

This is a fairly bare-bones new taxonomy, and there are plenty of other options available, of which there is a complete listing [in the WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy).

**UPDATE:**

I believe that this is what the whole loop would look like:

```
<?php
    wp_reset_query();
    $query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array( 
                    'taxonomy' => 'page_category',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => 541
                )
            )
        )
    );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <div>
<?php
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
                the_post_thumbnail( array(150,150) );
            else : ?>
                <img class="alignleft" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/empty_150_150_thumb.gif" width="150" height="150" />
<?php
            endif; ?>
                <div class="entry">
                    <h3 class="blog_header"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link: <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="button_link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span>Read More</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php
        endwhile;
    endif; ?>
```

Comment: This works, however, when I try to display these pages in a loop for a page template (I've updated my question with code) - it doesn't allow me to view the page...

Comment: I saw that Kudratullah fixed the error in the loop, so you should at least be seeing a non-blank page.  However, to query the proper taxonomy, replace 'cat' => 541 with this:  'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'page_category', 'field' => 'term_id', 'terms' => 541 ) ).  More info here:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: Thanks. But I still don't get how this would work, would you be able to post some code somewhere and send me a link so I can see the whole loop? Thanks.

Comment: Updated the post, see above.

Answer (score 2):

checkout this [solution by @Matoeil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323582/wordpress-how-to-add-categories-and-tags-on-pages)

```
function myplugin_settings() {  
// Add tag metabox to page
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'page'); 
// Add category metabox to page
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');  
}
 // Add to the admin_init hook of your theme functions.php file 
add_action( 'init', 'myplugin_settings' );
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, where and how should I add this?

Comment: in `functions.php` please :)

Comment: That worked, thanks so much. Do you have any idea on how to have the categories assigned only for pages? Because it's pulling the categories through for posts.. Thanks.

Comment: just change your query in your page template and add `post_type=page`. eg. `$query = new WP_Query( array( post_type=page, 'cat' => 4 ) );`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, just bring back a blank page!

Comment: sorry but your just copy and pasting blindly. above code should give php error, my bad. check your argument array...  `array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'cat' => 541 )`